# finding specific type of files in mac (python)

Tags: python, macos

I have a script that compiles few programs and puts the output into a folder, I have a function in my script that iterates and finds all the executables in the folder and adds them into a list,

```
def _oswalkthrough(direc,filelist=[]):
    dirList=os.listdir(direc)
    for item in dirList:
        filepath = direc+os.sep+item
        if os.path.isdir(filepath):
            filelist = _oswalkthrough(filepath,filelist)
        else:
            if ".exe" == item[-4:]:
                filelist.append(filepath)
    return filelist
```

This works with out any problem on windows, but when I run this on a mac, I can't get it to work, of course the compiled files in mac doesn't end with ".exe", so that if statement is useless, so I made a list that contains the name of the compiled files and changed the script to the following, but still no result, it adds all the files, including the ".o" files, which I do not want!. I just want the exe? (I don't know what they are called in mac !).

```
def _oswalkthrough(direc,filelist=[]):
    dirList=os.listdir(direc)
    for item in dirList:
        filepath = direc+os.sep+item
        if os.path.isdir(filepath):
            filelist = _oswalkthrough(filepath,filelist)
        else:
            for file in def_scons_exe:
                if file == item[-4:]:
                    filelist.append(filepath)
    return filelist
```

Comment: You should look up `os.walk`.  You can build this list without making `_oswalkthrough` recursive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the section:

```
for file in def_scons_exe:
    if file == item[-4:]:
        filelist.append(filepath)
```

Should be:

```
for file in def_scons_exe:
    if file == item[-len(file):]:
        filelist.append(filepath)
        break
```

This change makes the program look for extensions of any length, not just 4 characters. It also stops looking through the extensions when it finds one that matches.

Also, you should try using the [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/library/os#os.walk) function to simplify your code as well as [`os.access([path], os.X_OK)`](http://docs.python.org/library/os#os.access) to test for execute permissions.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your code doesn't work on Mac because, e.g, your condition `if file == item[-4:]` won't work for `.o` (their length is different, they won't be equal ever).

Another thing, take a look at `os.walk` function (it will save some space in your path traversing).

Another issue is that checking for extension doesn't guarantee the file is executable. You'd better use os.access to check for file access mode, in your case (you'd like to know if it's executable) you must check for `os.X_OK` flag. Here's a code snippet for check:

```
import os

if os.access("/path/to/file.o", os.X_OK):
    print 'Executable!'
```

Comment: I already have a separate function that checks, if a file is executable or not. The current function kept adding the .o files, I don't want them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use os.access to check it in mac, linux AND windows too:

```
def _oswalkthrough(direc,filelist=[]):
    dirList=os.listdir(direc)
    for item in dirList:
        filepath = os.path.join(direc,item)
        if os.path.isdir(filepath):
            filelist.extend(_oswalkthrough(filepath))
        elif os.access(filepath, os.X_OK):
            filelist.append(filepath)
    return filelist
```

I did some bug fixing and turn things more pythonic too.

Comment: It would also be useful to point out that `os.walk` is a much better alternative to this recursive function...

Answer (score 0):

The answer on a Mac is more difficult than on Windows.  The default binary extension on windows is exe.  There is no equivalent on a Mac.  There are binary file types. They are what could classically be compared to an exe on a Mac.  They reside in lots of places.  You can see a good chunk of them in /usr/bin.

To check if a binary file type is to check the file access mode:

```
is_executable = os.access(path, os.X_OK)
```

But when you say executable you could also be talking about an app folder.  Which, on a Mac, is what Windows user traditionally think of as exe's.  Most of the app folders reside in /Applications.

You can get a list of app folder like so:

```
import os

appfolder = [name for name in os.listdir(".") if os.path.isdir(name) and name.endswith('.app')]
```